# Display a table/list data dynamically in MVC3/Razor from a JsonResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a view page, users.cshtml. And I have a JsonResult action method, jsongetusers() that returns the list of users in json format.

On users.cshtml page load, I want to get the list of users, build a table and display it. What is the best way to implement this in ASP.Net MVC using Razor? I am pretty new to MVC3 and Razor. My initial thought was to loop through the json result and build a table using javascript/jquery and append it to the DOM. But I am guessing there must be a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use a different action method than the users page to populate the list?  This will be slower and require two requests rather than one.

Comment: For initial page load, I don't need two. But when paging through users list, I need to load the users list asynchronously. I thought why not call the same function for initial load too.

Comment: Which of the answers below answered your problem?

Answer (score 22):

As  Mystere Man suggested, getting just a view first and then again making an ajax call again to get the json result is unnecessary in this case. that is 2 calls to the server. I think you can directly return an HTML table of Users in the first call.

We will do this in this way. We will have a strongly typed view which will return the markup of list of users to the browser and this data is being supplied by an action method which we will invoke from our browser using an http request.

Have a **ViewModel for the User**

```
public class UserViewModel
{
  public int UserID { set;get;}
  public string FirstName { set;get;}
   //add remaining properties as per your requirement

}
```

and in your controller have a method to get a list of Users

```
public class UserController : Controller
{

   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult List()
   {
     List<UserViewModel> objList=UserService.GetUsers();  // this method should returns list of  Users
     return View("users",objList)        
   }
}
```

Assuming that UserService.GetUsers() method will return a List of UserViewModel object which represents the list of usres in your datasource (Tables)

and in your users.cshtml ( which is under Views/User folder),

```
 @model List<UserViewModel>

 <table>

 @foreach(UserViewModel objUser in Model)
 {
   <tr>
      <td>@objUser.UserId.ToString()</td>
      <td>@objUser.FirstName</td>
   </tr>
 }
 </table>
```

All Set now you can access the url like `yourdomain/User/List` and it will give you a list of users in an HTML table.

Answer (score 9):

If you really need to go this way, then this is what you can do.  There are probably better ways of doing it, but this is all that I have at the moment.  I did no database calls, I just used dummy data.  Please modify the code to fit in with your scenario.  I used `jQuery` to populate the `HTML table`.

In my controller I have the an action method called `GetEmployees` that returns a `JSON result` with all the employees.  This is where you would call your repository to return the users from a database:

```
public ActionResult GetEmployees()
{
     List<User> userList = new List<User>();

     User user1 = new User
     {
          Id = 1,
          FirstName = "First name 1",
          LastName = "Last name 1"
     };

     User user2 = new User
     {
          Id = 2,
          FirstName = "First name 2",
          LastName = "Last name 2"
     };

     userList.Add(user1);
     userList.Add(user2);

     return Json(userList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The User class looks like this:

```
public class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In your view you could have the following:

```
<div id="users">
     <table></table>
</div>

<script>

     $(document).ready(function () {

          var url = '/Home/GetEmployees';

          $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

               $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                    var user = '<tr><td>' + val.FirstName + '</td></tr>';

                    $('#users table').append(user);

               });
          });
     });

</script>
```

Regarding the code above: `var url = '/Home/GetEmployees';` `Home` is the controller and `GetEmployees` is the action method that you defined above.

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

This is how I would have done it..

I always create a view model class for a view.  In this case I would have called it something like `UserListViewModel`:

```
public class UserListViewModel
{
     IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I would populate this Users list from a call to the database returning all the users:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
     UserListViewModel viewModel = new UserListViewModel
     {
          Users = userRepository.GetAllUsers()
     };

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

And in my view I would have the following:

```
<table>

@foreach(User user in Model.Users)
{
     <tr>
          <td>First Name:</td>
          <td>user.FirstName</td>
     </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: The second method will work but it will get performance penalty on large amount of pooling. It is always better to use JSon and then build data view in user browser then build the same view on server side on large amount of http calls.

Answer (score 2):

Add a View:

1. Right-Click View Folder
2. Click *Add -> View*
3. Click *Create a strongly-typed view*
4. Select your *User* class
5. Select *List* as the *Scaffold template*

Add a controller and action method to call the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = DataContext.GetUsers();
    return View(users);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal way of doing it is:

- You get the users from the database in controller.
- You send a collection of users to the View
- In the view to loop the list of users building the list.

You don't need a JsonResult or jQuery for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with the [KoGrid](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid) plugin for KnockoutJS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        window.viewModel = {
            myObsArray: ko.observableArray([
                { id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', createdOn: '1/1/2012', birthday: '1/1/1977', salary: 40000 },
                { id: 1, firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Harper', createdOn: '1/2/2012', birthday: '2/1/1976', salary: 45000 },
                { id: 1, firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Carrey', createdOn: '1/3/2012', birthday: '3/1/1985', salary: 60000 },
                { id: 1, firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'DiMaggio', createdOn: '1/4/2012', birthday: '4/1/1991', salary: 70000 }
            ])
        };

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>

<div data-bind="koGrid: { data: myObsArray }">
```

[Sample](http://ericmbarnard.github.com/KoGrid/examples/SimpleExample.html)