# How can I create a List<ViewModel> with 2 other classes of models? MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, mapping

How can I create a List< ViewModel > with 2 other classes of models?

1 Model:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int QuantityInBase { get; set; }
    public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
}
```

2 Model:

```
public class JsonViewModel
    {
        public List<JsonItem> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see above - both classes have property Code - it's connector.

3 Model (target ViewModel)

```
public class ItemViewModel
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int QuantityInBase { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemListViewModel
    {
        public List<ItemViewModel> ItemViewList;
    }
```

And this is what I was trying to do in controller already.

```
      public ActionResult ItemsListPartial(JsonViewModel webSocketData)
    //webSocketData has values from webservice
            {
                ItemListViewModel model = new ItemListViewModel();
                var data = db.Items.ToList();

                foreach (var obj in data)
                {
                    model.ItemViewList = ...
                    // here, somehow i have to merge !var data! with                      
                    // !webSocketData! = and it has to be one 
                    // list of ItemListViewModel
                }

                return View("_ItemsListPartial", model);
            }
```

It was hard to explain. I hope you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can create a `linq join` query on `code` property.
Something like:

```
var rez= (from p in data
          join q in webSocketData.Items on p.Code equals q.Code
          select new ItemViewModel
          { 
            ItemId = p.ItemId,
            Code = p.Code,
            Name = q.Name,
            QuantityInBase = p.QuantityInBase ,
            Price = q.Price,
            IsHidden = p.IsHidden
          }).ToList();
```

This will return a list of `ItemViewModel` in a `leftOuterJoin` manner.

Comment: I've an error: "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'."

Comment: Ok i changed to: "join q in webSocketData.Items" i'll test now. brb

Comment: Ok works fine! However how can I display this list on my view? "return View("_ItemsListPartial", rez);". And at view added: "@model List<FP.WebUI.ViewModels.ItemViewModel>" but still i cannot use: "@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)"

Comment: @DiPix Because you have a list as a `Model`. So you have to iterate through all the items. something like : `@(foreach var item in Model) Html.DisplayNameFor(item.Code)`

Comment: @DiPix, if you're using Visual Studio, you can let it create your partial view. Click on addView and a template will show up, select a model there (for you it's `ItemViewModel`), check the PartialView and select List from the templates there.

Comment: Yes i know, but it has to be table. And i wonder how to add table header.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815455/display-a-table-list-data-dynamically-in-mvc3-razor-from-a-jsonresult